# openvpn server not showing traffic using tcpdump

Tags: routing, openvpn, tcpdump

I have an OpenVPN server and two clients,

I can ping clients from each other, but when I do so, I don't see any packets on the server using tcpdump

#### Server

is running on 192.168.0.1

and I try to capture traffic using `tcpdump -i tun0 icmp --immediate-mode -l -n`

#### Clients

is running on 192.168.0.2

and I can ping client2 `ping 192.168.0.3` which resolves fine:

```
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=32.4 ms
```

#### TCP Dump

but I can't see anything from tcpdump:

```
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Although if I ping the openvpn server directly `ping 192.168.0.1`, I can see packets being captured there:

```
18:05:04.022747 IP 192.168.0.2 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 5, seq 5, length 64
18:05:04.022801 IP 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 5, seq 5, length 64
```

How can I capture inter-client communication packets on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `client-to-client` option, there is no way to see it with tcpdump. In this case OpenVPN doesn't forward any traffic to the kernel. It receives a packet, processes it and sends to another client, but since it is not destined for the server system nor routed through it, there is no need to emit it to the `tun` device.

You can see if traffic is inside OpenVPN by using a management console and a high verbosity level (6):

In server config file:

```
...
management localhost 7505
...
```

Use:

```
$ telnet localhost 7505
...
>INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info
log on
SUCCESS: real-time log notification set to ON
verb 6
SUCCESS: verb level changed
>LOG:1612639797,D,XXXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX UDPv4 READ [XXX] from [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX (via [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%XXX): P_DATA_V2 kid=2 DATA len=XXX
>LOG:1612639797,D,XXXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX TUN WRITE [XXX]
>LOG:1612639797,D,XXXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX TUN READ [XXX]
>LOG:1612639797,D,XXXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX UDPv4 WRITE [XXX] to [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX (via [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%XXX): P_DATA_V2 kid=2 DATA len=XXX
...
log off
SUCCESS: real-time log notification set to OFF
verb 3
SUCCESS: verb level changed
exit
$
```

(In this case I had to write 'log off' blindly, because output was completely disturbed by the real time log. I've done this on busy server. But it worked anyway.)

See `man openvpn` for details. Note, everything will also reach a server log file if it's used, and for a high amount of traffic there will be very large log. AFAIK you can even made it to log packet data in hex form.

Comment: so if I want to see this traffic and apply some advanced routing with iptables I would have to create two servers and forward traffic from one to another in order to hit kernel (and apply ip tables rules)?

Comment: I just tested that and it works like a charm :) thanks a lot for clarification about packets not hitting kernel with client-to-client option